# Install/update globally from github source instead of crates.io

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have installed trunk cargo [pkg globally](https://github.com/thedodd/trunk), but there was a bug that is fixed in master but not released yet on crates.

Is there a way to install/update my trunk from github source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`cargo install`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-install.html) accepts a `--git` command line option:

```sh
cargo install --git https://github.com/thedodd/trunk.git trunk
```